# Unable to perform dependency injection in MVC 5 Web API project using Castle Windsor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Below is the code for controller I want to instantiate using Windsor Castle.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private ITestService _testService = null;

    public TestController(ITestService testService)
    {
        _testService = testService;
    }

    public IList<TestClass> Get()
    {
        IList<TestClass> testObjects = _testService.GetAll().ToList();
        return testObjects;
    }
}
```

I've written following code in Global.asax.cs

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ........................

        InitializeServiceLocator();
    }

    private static void InitializeServiceLocator()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());

        var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(_container.Kernel);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
    }
```

Here is the code for installer =>

```
    public class ControllerInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }

        if (store == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("store");
        }
        //All MVC controllers
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IHttpController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());

        AddComponentsTo(container);
    }

    private void AddComponentsTo(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        container.Register(
             ///DBContext
             Component.For<DbContext>().ImplementedBy<SCFEntities>().LifestyleTransient());

        container.Register(
                            Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyProject.ApplicationServices").Pick().WithService.DefaultInterfaces().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyProject.Data").Pick().WithService.DefaultInterfaces().LifestylePerWebRequest());
    }
}
```

The problem is the controller instance is not created using parameterized constructor. It is expecting a parameterless constructor. Could anybody point out where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that you registered a controller factory for MVC, but Web API has a different interception point. You need to register the Web API DependencyResolver.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to read all the articles regarding WEB API that Mark Seemann wrote.
You can start [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectioninASP.NETWebAPIwithCastleWindsor/) and then traverse the archive for Web API [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/archive.html).

Read the first article and then traverse the archive. Everything is here.