# Web Api Owin Castle Windsor resolving controllers

Tags: castle-windsor, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm trying to use web api owin selfhosted - and resolving my controllers ( with parameters in the constructor). I've been researching extensively but cannot find an example that does this.
Can anyone provide some info ? or a lead ?

thanks !

Comment: Be sure you have read all the articles that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26624824/1042934) link points to. Everything is explained there.

Comment: have you tried that with OWIN selfhost? i've read his articles and used his techniques with web api - but owin requires some middleware.. and the dependency resolver registration is diffrent than what his article states ( for the new web API). have you actually tried it ? and it work for you with paramatrized constructors ? dont get me wrong ! thanks for your comments !!

Comment: Sorry, but I did notice the OWIN part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue i was having had to do with namespaces as my controllers are in a different assembly to my actual server. 
The article suggested in the comments by Ognyan Dimitrov helped a lot !

thanks